# Do I need a transvit visa for a 2 days stay in London?

Tags: visas, uk, london, canadian-citizens, stopovers

I am a Canadian PR holder with an Indian passport. I am planning to visit London for 3 days on my way to India. What kind of visa will I need? I will be going out in London and rent a car to see the whole city.

Comment: If you want to see any of London, other than the back of the car in front of you, do not rent a car.

Comment: Expanding on my earlier comment, London has a major public transit system, [Transport for London](https://tfl.gov.uk/). Often, buses move faster than cars, because the buses have special lanes and priority. The tube is much faster than road travel. The river boats give interesting views as well as being practical for some journeys.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. This question is about a _stopover_, whereas the canonical "layover" question assumes that the passenger will be continuing soon after landing -- certainly not stay for 3 days.

Answer (score 2):

A 3-day stop is too long to qualify for a "Visitor in Transit" visa, which is only good for up to 48 hours on UK soil.

You therefore need to apply for a **Standard Visitor Visa** (or shorten your stay so you will leave within 48 hours of arriving).

Comment: So that means if i reduce my stay to only 2 days than i can get transit visa and also be able to roam around the city as i want to celebrate my birthday over there.

Comment: The limit is 48 hours, so be careful about your flight times.